# Limitar cantidad de carácteres se muestran en un asp:CheckboxList

Tags: asp.net, asp

Tengo un checklist con repeatlayout estos datos los traigo de una base de datos
pero cuando los nombres son muy largos me mueve la caja y quiero que cuando se sobre pase 10 caracteres se corte.
ya he buscado en en la comunidad en ingles sin encontrar solución.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList RepeatLayout="table" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="vertical" ID="listas" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem>Item de nombre muy largo</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Item de nombre muy largo</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Item de nombre muy largo</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 0):

me auto respondo espero les pueda servir

en el checkboxlist limitar en *.asp.vb

```
For Each row As ListItem In CBLcheckboxlist.Items
                        If row.Text.Length > 32 Then
                            row.Text = Mid(row.Text, 1, 32) & "..."
                        End If
                    Next
```

siendo 32 el numero de caracteres